# Bubble Sorting - How to use it?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

Im a bit new to programming , Trying to get the idea of Algorithm so i started by Sorting Algorithms.So ive read a lot about it and tried to understand its idea then started by Bubble Sort,But im having a problem in my code , Can someone tell me if im thinking over this correctly ? Im not sure that im still on the right way for this.

EDIT: I want to have the user insert a certain amount of numbers in an array , Then these unarranged numbers to be swapped using the Bubble-Sort.

so here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[6];
    int temp;
    cout << "Enter an unarranged amount of numbers(6) \n";
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Normal List : ";
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
      //Sorting
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int x=0;x=i+1;x++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[x]){
                temp=arr[x];
                arr[x]=arr[i];
                arr[i]=temp;
            }
        }
         cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "But im having a problem in my code" what is the problem? Please provide a sample input, an expected output, and an actual output please!

Comment: For now remove the user input and hard-code the array. One less thing to worry about while debugging.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo here: `arr[i}` Close brace should be `]`, not `}`

Comment: My compiler spotted: `x=i+1` in the exit condition of the `for` loop. This is an assignment, not a comparison. Not sure exactly what you want, but I'm pretty sure the obvious `x==i+1` is wrong. Anyway, if the compiler doesn't raise a warning over this, consult the compiler documentation on how to crank up the warning level. Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors, so turn them on and turn them up LOUD!

Comment: I intend to sort the numbers given from the user to be arranged , My problem is that im expecting the numbers to be arranged in the second ForLoop. But when I compile it , It only keeps showing me garbage numbers together as a list.

Comment: @Oliver_Queen the code as shown shouldn't compile. Can you copy paste the code that you're using?

Comment: @John My bad i fixed it , Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop

```
for(int x=0;x=i+1;x++){
```

is an infinite loop because in the condition of the loop there is used the assignment

```
x=i+1
```

So the value of x that is the value of the condition is never will be equal to 0.

And the bubble sort algorithm compares and swaps adjacent elements of an array.

Also you could use the standard function `std::swap` to swap elements of the array.

The loops that implement the bubble sort can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 6;

    int arr[N];

    std::cout << "Enter an unarranged amount of " << N << " numbers: ";

    for ( auto &item : arr ) std::cin >> item;

    std::cout << "Before sorting: ";
    for ( const auto &item : arr ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( size_t n = N, last = n; !( n < 2 ); n = last )
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( arr[i] < arr[i-1] )
            {
                std::swap( arr[i], arr[i-1] );
                last = i;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "After  sorting: ";
    for ( const auto &item : arr ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
Enter an unarranged amount of 6 numbers: 6 3 1 2 4 5
Before sorting: 6 3 1 2 4 5 
After  sorting: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

As for your code then the inner loop should look at least like

```
    for(int x = 1; x < 6; x++ ){
        if ( arr[x-1] > arr[x] ){
            temp=arr[x];
            arr[x]=arr[x-1];
            arr[x-1]=temp;
        }
    }
```

and remove this statement after the loop

```
cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the clearance above and for the code , But isnt it possible to change the condition of **x** in order to stay finite ?

Comment: @Oliver_Queen Yes, you can. Just initialize x with 1, write the condition x < 6  and compare arr[x] with arr[x-1]